# openssl fails to build with pip install

Tags: python, gcc

Please help.

Trying to install python cryptography package:

`pip install trigger`

> gcc -pthread -B /home/dan/.conda/envs/py27/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/dan/.conda/envs/py27/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
>     build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:493:10: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
>       493 | #include

using conda with python 2.7 virtual env

Comment: do you have openssl installed?

Comment: ...and its headers / dev package?